# Exchange Transaction/Widthrawal Fees - i don't get it

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins

Guys i am trying to understand how does a 'transaction fee' work and 'widthrawal fee' work on all BTC Exchanges.

Let's simply things and assume i want to BUY BTC on an Exchange that has 0.45% fee for transaction.

The BTC Price currently is 1000$
I have 500$ meaning i would buy 0.5BTC.

Ok, so i paid the Exchange 500$ and created an BUY Order.
Immediately in a second it was Matched with a opposite order that was:
SELL 3 BTC @ 1000$

So i Got my 0.5BTC for 500$
And his order is now 2.5BTC @ 1000$

1) So do i have my 0.5BTC or it was reduced by 0.48% ?
Giving: 0.5BTC - (0.5BTC * 0.048) = 0.5 - 0.024 = 0,476BTC ?

2) What if my Order was partially filled (0.25BTC and 0.25BTC) - does that mean that the fee is applied to both 0.25BTC and 0.25BTC or for the Sum (0.5)

Comment: This is Bitcoin related insofar as the currency in the example is bitcoin. This is really a question about exchange rates, and how they work.

Comment: @KJO Those questions are ontopic.

Comment: Not really about bitcoin. Question is about procedures (subject to change anyway) of a specific exchange (without naming which one).

Comment: Your math is off, it should be `0.5 - (0.5 * 0.048/100) = 0.49976`

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie  Shouldn't that be 0.0048 ?

EXAMPLE: 0.0113 BTC @ 1149.00USD WHERE FEE = 0.48%

MY FEE = 0.0113 * 0.0048  = 0.00005424
YOURFEE = 0.0113 * (0.048/100) = 0.000005424

In your example there is one extra 0